# How to customize SharePoint Online modern search results (externally indexed from data source) shows on top in All search vertical?

Tags: sharepoint-online, microsoft-search

Externally indexed search results not populating at the top of All search vertical tab. Checked "All" vertical's content source and it's automatically checked "All" content source.  Checked All verticals properties, and defined external queryable properties (over 10) isn't listed in SharePoint search schema.

Answer (score 0):

Turned out, this is not available at the moment. However, it will be available (GA) in March 2023.

Ref: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/roadmap?filters=&searchterms=93336